# Millions of rows auto-complete field - implementation ideas?

Tags: database, memcached

I have a location auto-complete field which has auto complete for all countries, cities, neighborhoods, villages, zip codes. This is part of a location tracking feature I am building for my website. So you can imagine this list will be in the multi-millions of rows. Expecting over 20 million atleast with all the villages and potal codes. To make the auto-complete work well I will use memcached so we dont hit the database always to get this list. It will be used a lot as this is the primary feature on the site. But the question is:

Is only 1 instace of the list stored in memcached irrespective of the users pulling the info or does it need to maintain a separate instance for each? So if say 20 million people are using it at the same time, will that differ from just 1 person using the location auto-complete? I am open to other ideas also on how to implement this location auto complete so it performs well.

Or can i do something like this: When a user logs in in the background I send them the list anyways, so by the time they reach the auto complete textfield their computer will have it ready to load instant?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (or Lucene itself), using NGram (or EdgeNGram) tokenizers you can get good autocomplete performance on massive datasets.

Comment: Can I use Sphinx instead? Flow is like this: These are AJAX based fields so I need to hit them from AJAX. Other thing is I need GIS searching anyways so I prefer to use only one technology which can help with all needs instead of supporting multiple technologies.

Comment: Solr is designed specifically for Ajax queries. I don't know much about Sphinx, but it seems comparable to Lucene/Solr.  Just glancing over their site, they seem to be emphasizing indexing throughput and direct integration with relational databases; Lucene on the other hand seems to have more features, especially around text analysis. From what I've heard, their search performance is fairly similar (highly dependent on the specific use-case, of course). Since they implement the same data model, I would assume their GIS capabilities are similar, as well.